# Two blocks in the same frame?

Tags: beamer, animations

is it possible to add an animation to have both blocks in the same frame

Thank you

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Conclusion}
    \begin{block}{Conclusions}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Pour être plus fidèle à la réalité, le modèle peut être amélioré en prenant en

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    considération d’autres aspects physiques (pli d’enveloppe, aéroélasticité. . . ).

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    \item<2-> Une analyse par éléments finis sur la structure de l’engin peut être intéressante pour

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    dégager des données aérodynamiques en relation avec les surfaces de contrôle qui

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    peuvent servir pour une commande plus précise et plus avancée.

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    \item<3-> Utilisant ces données, une comparaison en simulations du modèle linéarisé et celui non

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    linéaire sera possible et éventuellement fructueuse.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

   \begin{block}{Recommandations}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Pour être plus fidèle à la réalité, le modèle peut être amélioré en prenant en

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    considération d’autres aspects physiques (pli d’enveloppe, aéroélasticité. . . ).

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    \item<2-> Une analyse par éléments finis sur la structure de l’engin peut être intéressante pour

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    dégager des données aérodynamiques en relation avec les surfaces de contrôle qui

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    peuvent servir pour une commande plus précise et plus avancée.

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    \item<3-> Utilisant ces données, une comparaison en simulations du modèle linéarisé et celui non

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    linéaire sera possible et éventuellement fructueuse.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could show them after each other. (I had to shrink your hard coded spaces because even a single block did not fit on the slide)

```
    \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Conclusion}

\begin{onlyenv}<1-3>
     \begin{block}{Conclusions}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Pour être plus fidèle à la réalité, le modèle peut être amélioré en prenant en

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    considération d’autres aspects physiques (pli d’enveloppe, aéroélasticité. . . ).

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    \item Une analyse par éléments finis sur la structure de l’engin peut être intéressante pour

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    dégager des données aérodynamiques en relation avec les surfaces de contrôle qui

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    peuvent servir pour une commande plus précise et plus avancée.

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    \item Utilisant ces données, une comparaison en simulations du modèle linéarisé et celui non

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    linéaire sera possible et éventuellement fructueuse.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<4->
   \begin{block}{Recommandations}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Pour être plus fidèle à la réalité, le modèle peut être amélioré en prenant en

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    considération d’autres aspects physiques (pli d’enveloppe, aéroélasticité. . . ).

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    \item Une analyse par éléments finis sur la structure de l’engin peut être intéressante pour

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    dégager des données aérodynamiques en relation avec les surfaces de contrôle qui

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    peuvent servir pour une commande plus précise et plus avancée.

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    \item Utilisant ces données, une comparaison en simulations du modèle linéarisé et celui non

    \vspace{0.15cm}
    linéaire sera possible et éventuellement fructueuse.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Elyes You're welcome!